# React Redux best practices for performing actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Where should I perform actions (redirecting or adding/removing something to/in the localstorage) in React (and Redux)? So after the password is successfully updated I want to redirect the user to another page. Should I redirect after the dispatch method, should I do it in the component or are there other options?

Example action:

```
export function updateAccountPassword(encryptedPassword) {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.post(API_URL + '/account/recovery/update', {
            _id: getSignedInUserID(),
            password: encryptedPassword
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch(updateUserPasswordSuccess())
        }).catch(() => {
            dispatch(updateUserPasswordFailError());
        })
    }
}

function updateUserPasswordSuccess() {
    return({
        type: RECOVERY_UPDATE_SUCCESS
    })
}

function updateUserPasswordFailError() {
    return({
        type: RECOVERY_UPDATE_FAIL_ERROR,
        payload: 'Something went wrong, please try again'
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I am doing it is by passing the `this.props.history.push` as a callback to the action creator, and calling it, as you suggested, in the action creator, after dispatch.

Here is an example from my code:

In the component form's submission, calling the action creator:

```
this.props.ACTION_CREATOR(formPayload, () => {
  this.props.history.push(`ROUTING_TARGET`);
});
```

And, then, in the action creator, when the proper condition has been met, calling the callback (rerouting).